# Insert class in PHP code for Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am a bit of a beginner in php and I am trying to target 3 text outputs in a php file and give them a unique class so I can style them via css.

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

$customer_id = get_current_user_id();
if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && get_option( 'woocommerce_calc_shipping' ) !== 'no' ) {
$page_title = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_title', __('My Addresses:', 'woocommerce') );
$get_addresses    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses', array(
    'billing' => __( 'Billing Address:', 'woocommerce' ),
    'shipping' => __( 'Shipping Address:', 'woocommerce' )
), $customer_id );
} else {
$page_title = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_title', __( 'My Address:', 'woocommerce' ) );
$get_addresses    = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses', array(
    'billing' =>  __( 'Billing Address:', 'woocommerce' )
), $customer_id );
}
$col = 1;
?>
```

I am trying to target 'My Addresses:' as well as 'Billing Address:' and 'Shipping Address:'.

I have worked with this just a bit before and I never had to add a class inside php code, but surely it must be possible, but I can't seem to find any info on where exactly to add my div class, p class etc..

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot,

Vaya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the woocommerce filters to wrap it with whatever you want. Put something like this in your functions.php:

```
function filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_address_title( $var ) { 
    return '<span class="your-class-here">'.$var.'</span>'; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_title', 'filter_woocommerce_my_account_my_address_title', 10, 1 ); 

function filter_woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses( $array, $customer_id ) { 
    $array['billing'] = '<span class="class-name-here">'.$array['billing'].'</span>';
    $array['shipping'] = '<span class="another-class-name-here">'.$array['shipping'].'</span>';
    return $array; 
}; 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses', 'filter_woocommerce_my_account_get_addresses', 10, 2 );
```

Remeber that if these elements are unique, the id attribute could be a better option.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late follow-up, but I was extremely busy :) Your fix worked perfectly, thanks a million for this! 1A+

Answer (score 0):

if you go to `woocommerce/templates/myaccount/my-address.php`

in line 42, you must have code like below:

```
<div class="col-<?php echo ( ( $col = $col * -1 ) < 0 ) ? 1 : 2; ?> address">
```

change code to:

```
<div class="col-<?php echo ( ( $col = $col * -1 ) < 0 ) ? 1 : 2; ?> address <?php echo str_replace(" ", "-", $title); ?>">
```

That will do the trick.